# Disable linter only in development mode not when try to commit changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have this code which is obviously failing by the linter
`console.log('asd', {asd:'asd'});`

```
Line 76:23:  Replace `asd:'asd'` with `·asd:·'asd'·`  prettier/prettier
```

and the thing is that this error is happening when I ran yarn start on every change. I know how to solve this lint error but I want the linter to work only when changes are tried to being commited which this is already working with Husky, not when I run yarn start and making development/debug/code review changes.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "@advisorycloud/golden-gate-web-users",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@advisorycloud/react-ui-components": "1.1.37",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.11",
    "formik": "^2.1.7",
    "formik-material-ui": "^3.0.0",
    "i18next": "^19.6.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.21",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.7.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn translate && react-scripts start",
    "build": "yarn translate && react-scripts build",
    "test-menu": "react-scripts test --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit",
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --watchAll=false --env jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "tdd": "react-scripts test --env jsdom-fourteen",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "eslint": "eslint ./src",
    "cy": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "cy:noapp:tests": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cy:run &&  yarn test",
    "cy:merge": "junit-merge --dir ./__cytests__ --out ./__cymerge__/cypressresults.xml",
    "tests:merge:allreports": "junit-merge --out ./__finalreport__/finalreport.xml ./__jest-junit-reports__/junit.xml ./__cymerge__/cypressresults.xml",
    "clear:reports": "rm -r ./__cymerge__/* && rm -r ./__cytests__/* && rm -r ./__finalreport__/* && rm -r ./__jest-junit-reports__/* || true ",
    "full:test": "yarn clear:reports && yarn cy:noapp:tests && yarn cy:merge && yarn tests:merge:allreports",
    "translate": "npx translate --source ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "outputDirectory": "./__jest-junit-reports__",
    "outputName": "junit.xml",
    "uniqueOutputName": "false",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname}-{title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " › ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@advisorycloud/translation": "^1.1.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.9",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.3",
    "cypress": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "husky": ">=4",
    "jest-junit": "^11.1.0",
    "junit-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.4"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged && yarn test"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint --cache",
    "*.jsx": "eslint --cache"
  }
}
```

and this is my linter configuration

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2020": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "node": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier", "plugin:cypress/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "jsx-a11y", "import", "prettier", "jest", "cypress"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      2,
      {
        "extensions": ["index.js", ".jsx"]
      }
    ],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "jest/no-disabled-tests": 0,
    "jest/no-focused-tests": "error",
    "jest/no-identical-title": "error",
    "jest/prefer-to-have-length": "warn",
    "jest/valid-expect": "error",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
      "error",
      {
        "devDependencies": [
          "**/*.test.js",
          "**/*.test.jsx",
          "**/*.spec.js",
          "**/*.spec.jsx",
          "**/setupTests.js"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting": 0
  }
}
```

Sorry for my english and anticipated thanks

Comment: to solve this error you just need space `console.log('asd', {asd: 'asd'});`

Comment: Yeah i know how to resolve that error but what I need is eslint to work just when try to commit, not when I run yarn start

Comment: that's no meaning to do that, if you want to solve it at the commit stage, why not now?

Comment: Because sometimes when we are doing code reviews and want to make quick changes in order to test functionality, this behaviour wastes time

Comment: I agree that the code needs to be within the project eslint configuration rules but it is not necessary to have always perfect code when we are doing code just for debug

Comment: how? is it wasting the time? I think you didn't add an auto format thing that reformat your code when you save ( ctrl + s )

Comment: I didnt added the linter with that purpose thats why im asking this

Comment: you cant disable it eslint in development mode and turn on it commit, for now that's not possible

Comment: Thank you sir that`s all I was asking for

Comment: great, so should I post it as an answer?